# Inserting Dynamic amount of rows from Form into Table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**Form:**

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="px">
<thead>
<tr class="tab_head">
<td width="25px" style="text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">#</td>
<td class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">First Name</td>
<td class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">Last Name</td>
<td class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">Wgt</td>
<td class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">Address</td>
<td class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">Phone</td>
<td class="form_label" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:11px;">Email</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbl1">
<tr id="pass">
<td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center"><input type="text" name="pass_num[]" readonly="readonly" value="1" class="pass" style="font:Verdana; font-size:11px; border:none; background-color:transparent; width:25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" tabindex="-1"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="cfn1" name="cust_fname[]" class="form_g" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="cln1" name="cust_lname[]" class="form_g" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cust_kg[]" class="form_a" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cust_addr[]" class="form_c" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cust_phone[]" class="form_g" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="cust_email[]" class="form_b" /></td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle"><a class="removePax"><img src="images/remove_pax.png" /></a></td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

**Table Columns:**

```
cust_id
cust_fname
cust_lname
cust_kg
cust_addr
cust_phone
cust_email
```

There is a snippet of JQuery that essentially clones the above table as required to allow the user to add another passenger etc. On submittinh, the data is posted to the next page fine, and I've tested numerous times that the data is coming through in Arrays (eg. `$_POST[cust_fname`] etc.).

The problem I'm having now is turning these into sets that I can insert into the table.

I tried a `foreach` loop and iterating but so far, I'm failing to come up with a solution. I have tried sorting the data into per passenger, but so far keeps clumping the data together.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5895bu0y/1/)

Comment: I can try, but I am unsure on how this is going to help, as the problem is a PHP/MySQL issue, not a JQuery issue?

Comment: Without knowing exactly how the jQuery copies the table, on our end it's effectively a guessing game.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5895bu0y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php code, you have to iterate with one **for** loop all the arrays in the same time and print them. Example :

```
cust_fname = $_POST["cust_fname"];
cust_lname = $_POST["cust_lname"];
for($i = 0; $i < count($cust_fname); $i++)
{
    echo "Complete name : ".$cust_fname[$i]." ".$cust_lname[$i];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I just put an example for two fields, you can do the rest :)

**EDIT :** I saw that you want to show them in a table, so you can change the code i gave you to :

```
cust_fname = $_POST["cust_fname"];
cust_lname = $_POST["cust_lname"];
echo "<table><tr><th>First name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr><tbody>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($cust_fname); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$cust_fname[$i]."</td><td> ".$cust_lname[$i]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table">;
```

Comment: This is sort of what I am looking for, the only issue is that these are still "echoing" as `Array`

Comment: I replaced $cust_fname with $cust_fname[$i] in the loop so it is the current element of the array that is shown not the array himself.

Comment: You sir, are my knight in shining armour! Thank you!

Comment: If you can do one more thing, using example 1, instead of echoing the `<br>`, is there any way there if there is another "customer" to be looped, it echos a `,` and if not then a `<br>`?